# Contact details are not showing in Micromax A47 Android Mobile?

Tags: contacts

In my Micromax A47 Android Mobile, I lost all my contacts but when I tried to call my recent contacts through my mobile it's showing their name. When I tried  to see my sim and phone contacts its showing only two but I had more contacts. When I inserted that sim in another mobile ( Not Android OS ) it's showing all my contacts. Why it's showing like this? Does this happens because of my mobile problem or OS problem?